# Laravel redirects login page after a delete operation

Tags: php, laravel

When I try to destroy a record with resource controller, laravel redirects to login page
although I applied auth middleware in the controller.

Laravel Version is 6.x.

**Web.php**

```
<?php
Auth::routes();

Route::resource('sliders', 'Admin\SliderController');
```

**SliderController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Slider;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use Validator;

class SliderController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

...other methods

    public function destroy(Slider $slider)
    {
        Slider::destroy($slider->id);

        Session::flush('status', 'success');

        return redirect('sliders');
    }
    }
}
```

I couldn't understand why it redirects to login page.

Help please

Thanks

Comment: I bellieve it's because you're using `Session::flush` instead of `Session::flash`.  `flush` will remove all the data from the session... And also the login.

Comment: `Session::flush('status', 'success');` to `Session::flash('status', 'success');`  https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/session#flash-data

Comment: Thank you. It was about flush.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Session flush is to delete all data https://laravel.com/docs/master/session#deleting-data

Use

```
$request->session()->flash('status', 'success');
```